# The below code is working very fine for the detached signature!! How to get attached signature?

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, openssl, openssl-engine

The result that I am getting in final is detached signature but my requirement is to get the attached signature.I must sign with my CSR file to get the attached signature using openssl.I have gone through a lot of websites but no one has provided the proper solution.

```
(NSData*)getSignature
{

unsigned char sha_buffer[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
memset((void*) sha_buffer, 0, SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH);
SHA256_Final(sha_buffer, &m_sha_ctx);

PKCS7 * p7 = PKCS7_new();
PKCS7_set_type(p7, NID_pkcs7_signed);

PKCS7_SIGNER_INFO* p7Si = PKCS7_add_signature(p7, mp_x509, mp_pkey, EVP_sha256());
PKCS7_add_attrib_content_type(p7Si, OBJ_nid2obj(NID_pkcs7_data));
PKCS7_add0_attrib_signing_time(p7Si, NULL);
PKCS7_add1_attrib_digest(p7Si, (const unsigned char*) sha_buffer, SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH);
PKCS7_add_certificate(p7, mp_x509);

int c = 0;
for ( ; c < sk_X509_num(mp_ca); c++) {
    X509* cert = sk_X509_value(mp_ca, c);
    PKCS7_add_certificate(p7, cert);
}

PKCS7_set_detached(p7, 1);

PKCS7_content_new(p7, NID_pkcs7_data);

PKCS7_SIGNER_INFO_sign(p7Si);

int p7Len = i2d_PKCS7(p7, NULL);
NSMutableData* signature = [NSMutableData data];
unsigned char* p7Buf = (unsigned char*) malloc(p7Len);
if (p7Buf != NULL) {
    unsigned char* pP7Buf = p7Buf;
    i2d_PKCS7(p7, &pP7Buf);
    [signature appendBytes: (const void*) p7Buf length: p7Len];
    free(p7Buf);
}
PKCS7_free(p7);

return (signature);
}
```

Comment: How to add my CSR as attribute in order to get attached signature?